# Wordpress Custom Post Type CSS & JS 404

Tags: css, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm having a weird problem on a Wordpress site that I've built. I set up custom post types for a portfolio site, circa Wordpress 2.8. Everything worked out great and it was on auto pilot. Somewhere between Wordpress 3.0 and 3.1, the `style.css` file started throwing out a 404, but **only** on the single post pages.

**EDIT** - It's actually every included file. CSS & JS. The plot thickens...

I'm baffled, and I don't even know where to start. I changed the permalinks, re-did the `.htaccess`file. Has anyone else ran into this problem?

Here's the link to the site if you want to FireBug it - http://artifexmakeup.com

Sorry, I would post some code, but I have no idea where the problem even begins... but let me know what you need to see, and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not linking to the style sheet somehow. I'll look at it in detail when I get off work. I would check the names of your classes in the CSS and make sure that the body class for the single post is named correctly. It appears that the reference to the stylesheet is in the head; I think that's ok. Nice photos!

Comment: All of the classes and structural whatnot is correct. The single post pages return a 404 error for the css file. Actually, it's every file...

Comment: No it's not ok. References are wrong, they contain **%postname%**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your files are specified with relative path, so you get wrong url.

```
http://artifexmakeup.com/patty-boring/wp-content/themes/ArtifexMakeup/html5-boilerplate/css/style.css?v=1301356717
```

Here `patty-boring/` messes up your urls.

I don't know how you specify urls in theme so I can't tell you where you're doing wrong.

Comment: ć Where are you getting that from? All of the URLs are fine when I look at them. When I enter that path in the browser, it goes straight to the file...

Comment: Here's how it looks for me...
http://cl.ly/2U230o3E0k423x1O3h1g
Here's how I'm linking to it.
`<?php versioned_stylesheet($GLOBALS["TEMPLATE_RELATIVE_URL"]."html5-boilerplate/css/style.css") ?>`

Comment: Since you changed permalink settings my answer is no longer valid ;)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's something with mod_pagespeed screwing with the custom post types. Thanks for your help!